# JavaScript: Trying to Understand The Else Statement of a Recursion Function Calculating Exponent Value

Tags: javascript, if-statement, recursion, input, exponent

I want to calculate exponents using recursion.  I have the code below which executes successfully.

```
function pow(base, exponent) {

  if (exponent <= 1){
    return base
  }

  else {
    return base * pow(base, exponent-1)
  }
}

// console.log(pow(3, 5)); // -> answer is 243
```

I am trying to understand the else case here.  In the else statement when the input argument for exponent is 2 or higher:

what does the `pow(base, exponent-1)` portion of `return base * pow(base, exponent-1)` return? Does it equal the base value?

Comment: calls your `pow` function with arguments, base and exponent - 1, and returns the result multiplied by base

Comment: fyi, `pow(x,0)` returns `x` but should always return `1` - you can fix this by adjusting the base case to `if (exponent === 0) return 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if you want to calculate `pow(2, 3) -- that is 2 raised to the 3rd power, or 8 -- this function does

```
                                                       (if)
                                         since 1 <= 1 ------+
                               (else)                       |
                   since 2 > 1 ------+                      |
                                     |                      |
            (else)                   |                      |
since 3 > 1 ------,                  |                      |
                  V                  V                      V
       pow(2, 3) ---> 2 * pow(2, 2) ---> 2 * 2 * pow(2, 1) ---> 2 * 2 * 2 -> 8
```

This is the essence of recursion: calling a function from inside the same function (or at least somewhere in the call-stack; see mutual recursion examples), using data that is in some way simpler; so that eventually you hit a base case you can calculate without such calls.

Answer (score 1):

Consider that `2 ** 3 == 2 * (2 ** 2)`
and `2 ** 2 == 2 * (2 ** 1)`

Substituting gives:

```
2 ** 3 == 2 * 2 * (2 ** 1)
```

This is all your recursive function is doing. When you call:

```
pow(2, 3)
```

That turns into:

```
base * pow(2, 2)
```

`pow(2, 2)`  turns into:

```
 base * pow(2, 1)
```

substitute give:

```
base * base * pow(2, 1)
```

`pow(2, 1)` is your base case which equals `base` so in the end you get

```
pow(2, 3) === base * base * base
```

One of the best tools for understanding recursion is the debugged. Just step through and see how the values are changing and what's on the stack.

Answer (score 0):

On each recursion, the function is called with 1 less than the exponent initially passed.

```
pow(base, exponent-1)
```

essentially counting down from it's initial value to 1, at which point it meets the condition where it stops recursing, and only returns the base.

```
if (exponent <= 1){
    return base
}
```

so if you pass pow(3, 4),

recursion 1 (`pow(3,4)`): `3 * // 3`

recursion 2 (`pow(3,3)`): `3 * // 9`

recursion 3 (`pow(3,2)`): `3 * // 27`

recursion 4 (`pow(3,1)`): `3 = // 81`

Answer (score 0):

It's a recursion function. Consider the recursion function F(n) in mathematic.
F(n, m) = n * F(n , m-1),
F(n, 1) = n.
So, the code just implement this function.

F(n) in the code is pow(base, exponent) which n is base and m is exponent.